# Does anybody remember a Facebook game about a floating island and goblins?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I used to play this game around 2014-15 on Facebook but I neither remember the name nor its main goal. What I do remember is that you appeared on a floating island where a big goblin is standing doing absolutely nothing. I don't know if you could trade with him but he couldn't move, it wasn't a very good game but I wanna remember it.

When you fell from the island, there was like a field with resources I think? You also had a place where you could build your house. The game was online so you could play with friends and go to some kind of dungeons with little goblins but the dungeons were more of a room than anything.

The characters and world were kind of cubical but with soft edges though the goblins were in goblin form. It was 3D and you played either in first or third person.

Comment: [Goblin Keeper?](https://www.browsergameslist.com/goblin-keeper.html)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a kid, so approximately what year was it when you were playing this game?